# Uspent unconfirmed and stuck transaction

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

My transaction is stuck and unspent, not sure what to do next, can any one help?

https://blockchain.info/tx/65ebc1410a65222f88f703b9bde14defc0014deafb4c2909abce3b21cbf6df66

Address it was going to

https://blockchain.info/address/1CxuudZouS6TKRo9kmSNgCbxnimVtjHgqr

It was sent from Alt trader, I am happy to pay more fees, though not sure how, as the exchange did the transfer.

Comment: accelerated. this transaction will be confirmed shortly. if you are willing to pay - my address is in profile

Comment: How much should I pay.

Comment: Hi, how much should I pay to accelerate the transaction ?

Comment: @AleksRudy wait for confirmation. For more info email me.

Comment: Please drop me a email with your address my email is aleksrudysa@gmail.com

Comment: alistermaclin@mail.ru

Answer (score 0):

According to blockchain.info, the transaction has a fee of 20 satoshis/byte. If you look at https://bitcoinfees.21.co/ you can see a summary of outstanding transactions and their fees, which currently shows there's higher fee/byte transactions for miners to include other transactions in their blocks before they get around to yours.

It will almost certainly confirm eventually. Otherwise, follow the link to the duplicate question, and there are some other suggestions.